# Order of the columns in Apache Zeppelin when selecting the data from the temprorary table is wrong, how to put specific column first?

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

Currently we have the scala `DataFrame` output with id value shown first (but it is chronologically added to the `DataFrame` last). Other columns appears dynamically based on `.pivot()` function and the data.

When I call for the data in `%sql` interpreter, the order is changing, thus making CSV file that I download also have id column as the last one, that doesn't work for me. I can't just write the selection script at once with putting the id column at the first point manually, as I can't control other columns because of pivot. Is there any other way to make specific column go first?

[image]

The Scala paragraph is:

```
resultMean.registerTempTable("mean")
```

The sql paragraph is:

```
%sql
select  *
from mean
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For someone who will read this in future, the reason of such a behavior is in misusing the `DataFrame`. In Scala `.show()` was applied to one DataFrame, while the export to the temp table to another one. If you face the same, please double check you apply your methods to the same objects.